# Node.js - Can't reach handlebars element from jquery using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I set a jquery function for whenever someone clicks on one of the avaliable "Delete" buttons it sends a request to "/burgers/delete/" + ("data-id" button attribute).
The problems is I can't reach the button "data-id" attribute. Is seems the "$(this)" is pointing to the window object.

app.js

```
$("button[id='delete']").on("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    $("button[id='delete']").attr("disabled","disabled")
    const id = $(this).attr("data-id")//I need the dynamc id here!

    $.ajax({
        url:"/burgers/delete/"+id,
        method: "DELETE",
        data: id
    }).then((id) => {
        deleteBurgerSuccess(id)
    }).catch((erro) => {
        deleteBurgerFails(erro)
    })
})
```

burgers.handlebars

```
{{#each burgers}}
        {{#unless is_favorite}}
            <div class="card mt-2 mx-auto" style="width: 30rem" id="burger">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4>{{burger_name}}</h4>
                    <br>    
                    <button data-id="{{id}}" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{else}}

        {{/unless}}
{{else}}
{{/each}}
```

My id keeps always being undefined giving me the browser console error:

DELETE http://localhost:9001/burgers/delete/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

I expect reaching the dynamic element which called this jquery function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does the event have a target property?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've never used it before. I'll look for it. Thank you.

Comment: If you call `console.log( event );` right where you have the `event.preventDefault()` call, you may be able to find a reference to your object in there.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code, is data-id actually there in the element?

Comment: After printing the jquery "event" I could find the id value I need to get. By the browser console it is in :  events > currentTarget > attributes > 0:data-id > nodeValue. I'll try to follow this path.

Yes, "data-id" is receiving the "{{id}}", value that I printed in the HTML and it is tottaly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("button[id='delete']").on("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    $("button[id='delete']").attr("disabled","disabled")
    const id = $(event.target).attr("data-id")//I need the dynamc id here!

    $.ajax({
        url:"/burgers/delete/"+id,
        method: "DELETE",
        data: id
    }).then((id) => {
        deleteBurgerSuccess(id)
    }).catch((erro) => {
        deleteBurgerFails(erro)
    })
})
```

Modify your code as shown above. $(this) has context bound to document object.You will need to access your element through event.target property.

Comment: Did you try the above code.You have to just change const id = $(this).attr("data-id") to const id = $(event.target).attr("data-id")

Comment: Yes, I did it and it worked! I could also reach this value using: event.currentTarget.attributes[0].nodeValue, since JasonB told us this value is inside the "event" variable. Thank you.